# Arduino IDE fails without sudo

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, ubuntu

I use Arduino IDE 1.6.6 on Ubuntu 15.10.

Starting the Arduino IDE without using `sudo` fails for both:

- uploading the code to the Arduino Uno
- starting the serial monitor

The group I need to add my user to is called `dialout`:

```
myuser@mycomputer:~$ ls -l /dev/ttyACM*
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 166, 0 Dez 12 17:57 /dev/ttyACM0
```

So I added `myuser` to `dialout`:

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout myuser
```

Somewhere I read that I have to add `myuser` to `tty` as well, so I did it:

```
sudo usermod -a -G tty myuser
```

Though I still fail with the above mentioned when trying to use the IDE with `myuser`.

What do I have to do to get the IDE working with `myuser`?

Comment: Have you logged out yet?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Oh, that was it. I had to log off and on again, something I rarely do. I feel so stupid now for not having tried that. Thanks for telling me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a command like 'id' or something similar that will show the groups you are a member of. Run that to check that the new groups have taken effect – you may need to log out and then log back in.

The other thing to check is the group owner of the device itself (in /dev). that will also need to match the group you assigned to yourself. Also make sure that the device permissions allow group access.

Comment: This is a very informal "solution", not too useful for beginners.